# Does react-google-charts built on top of google charts layer from google?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

Does react-google-charts built on top of google charts layer from google?? How stable is the library?

we want it to use for commercial purpose. Is it free?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.